# Modifiy column attribute using ADOX [ vc++ and MS Access]

Tags: ms-access, visual-c++

I have to add new columns in existing table. I can able to successfully add new column, but following exception occur while tying to modify the column attribute to nullable.

**Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done**

Here my code,

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
ADOX::_CatalogPtr pCatalog = NULL;
ADOX::_TablePtr pTable = NULL;
ADOX::TablesPtr pTables = NULL;

hr = pCatalog.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Catalog));
pCatalog->PutActiveConnection("Provider='Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0';data source='C:\\sample.mdb';");
pTables = pCatalog->GetTables();
pTable  = pTables->Item["sampletable"];


hr = pTable->Columns->Append( "age", ADOX::adInteger, 0);
ASSERT(hr == S_OK);
pTable->Columns->Item["age"]->Attributes = ADOX::adColNullable;
```

Comment: You are not using MS-Access. You are using Jet/ACE.

Comment: Nah, they're using Jet ;) Everyone calls it Access, even Microsoft. Even you know that.

Comment: @David W. Fenton: Rather than bother folk in comments and clutter the place up, you could have retagged the post instead. Also, you have 2k+ rep now so you can edit posts.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent code in VBA works for me without error (assuming I have translated it faithfully).

Something perhaps to try is to create a Column object, set its properties including NULLable then append it to the Table object's Columns collection e.g. this in VBA:

```
Set oColumn = New ADOX.Column
oColumn.Name = "age"
oColumn.Type = ADOX.adInteger
oColumn.Attributes = ADOX.adColNullable
oTable.Columns.Append oColumn
```